# Can I make grouped bars in plotly polar bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, bar-chart, polar-coordinates

I have a polar bar chart with stacked bars in plotly, which gives me the figure below using the code I've added as well (example found here: [Wind Rode Charts](https://plotly.com/python/wind-rose-charts/)):

[image]

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'svg'
#pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.wind()

fig = px.bar_polar(df, r="frequency", theta="direction",
                    color="strength", template="ggplot2",
                    color_discrete_sequence= px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.show()


fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="top",
    y=-0.2,
    xanchor="center",
    x=0.5),
    polar=dict(radialaxis=dict(showticklabels=True, ticks='', dtick=1, linewidth=0)
    )
)

fig.update_polars(angularaxis_dtick=1, 
                  angularaxis_exponentformat="power")

fig.show()
```

Now, I would like to group some bars together, similar to the figure below (examples [python graph gallery](https://python-graph-gallery.com/circular-barplot-with-groups)):

[image]

I cannot figure out how to do this with plotly so I keep both the stacked bars AND the grouping. Any hint or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide sample data? And will that data include grouping information? Because it wouldn't make sense for the data to be generated differently than your data.

Comment: I've run the sample plotly link you provided, and it doesn't seem to have the grouping functionality I expect. So I may only be able to intentionally insert blank spaces in the data and annotate the group name.

Comment: Yes, I didn't add grouping yet, since I wasn't sure how this should be done. But, le'ts say all directions/bars are each a group and then if some are occurring multiple times, e.g. if you triplicate all 'N'. Then, could I have all bars by themselves, but then three bars for N grouped closer together? I would also be interesting in knowing how you insert blank spaces and annotate group names.

Comment: The data structure of this graph is an array or list in the shape of a doughnut of a circle, so by inserting empty data such as '' between groups, it becomes a missing state. (like a whole cake that has been divided)

Comment: Do you by any chance know if I can make the bars in different sizes/widths?